# how do we perform time-series walk forward analysis

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

I recently came across the technique called as walk forward time-series analysis which is equivalent to cross-validation technique for non-time-series problem. In this I learnt, that we decide the min number of training samples and we test on the subsequent few test samples or 1 test sample.

We further include these test samples or test sample into next training and then test on the same number of subsequent test samples as in the previous case. This process goes on and we get multiple models with different or same training sizes(Expanding or sliding) and same test sizes. At the end, we average out the performance of these models.

This performance is considered for one-set of hyperparameters and we try this analysis for other such configurations and whichever configuration gives the best average performance, that set of hyperparameters or configuration is finally selected. Another way we say this is GridSearching the hyperparameters.

However, I have got confused with the nested approach given on the link : https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-nested-cross-validation-76adba623eb9
It says to take out the validation subset from the training, and for every training, it chooses different hyperparamters and average out the performance, which makes less sense to me. Since, for every model, hyperparamters are different which defeats the purpose of knowing that a configuration which will give good results as we get the data in temporal order. Also, there shouldn't be the need to select the model on validation and we can directly take the hyperparamters which give good average performance on test set.

This is so because the validation set is needed to get the good generalized performance and avoid overfitting. In the above scenario, by training different models with the same random initializations and same set of hyperparamters or configuration, we do the testing multiple times and try to know if the model works well or not i.e generalizing or not. Can someone pls clarify if I am thinking right or wrong? I am new to this type of time-series analysis. Your help would make my job easier as I am currently working on some similar problem.

Comment: I'm doing some research on exactly the same topic. I agree with you. If you want to generalize in the best possible way, and not overfit, then should you use the set of hyperparameters which perform the best in ALL the out of sample sets. However, one may argue that in time series phenomenons most recent events are more important that those from the past, so that the hyperparameters fitted to the most recent out of sample sets may work best with unknown test sets from the future.
Let's hope that someone with a bit more experience on the topic can shed some light on us.